# For WSO2 URLs in the same subnet, the WSO2 hazelcast is distributed even when clustering is disabled.

Tags: hazelcast, wso2, wso2-esb

We have disabled the clustering in WSO2 like the below in axis2.xml.

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="false">
```

The following is our code in WSO2 java mediator. What we are finding is that even if the clustering is disabled as mentioned above, when there are 2 WSO2 URLs in the same sub net (the URLS are http://192.168.111.111/carbon/admin/login.jsp and http://192.168.111.144/carbon/admin/login.jsp respectively), the cache becomes distributed. The value that we put to the cache in the 1st URL is reflected in the 2nd URL also.

```
public Map getMapInstance(String cacheName)
{
    int tenantId = getCurrentTenantId();

    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    String key = new StringBuilder().append(cacheName).append(Utils.SEPARATOR).append(tenantId).toString();
    Map map = instance.getMap(key); 
    return map;
}



putValueInCache(String cacheName)
{

    Map map = getMapInstance(cacheName);
    map.("KEY", "OBJECT");

}
```

Looking forward to some tips on this.

Sujith Babu

Comment: Why are you creating new HazelcastInstance every time ? You should be using the existing instance that is created by ESB.

Comment: How do I get access to the existing instance programmatically in our custom java mediator? Not sure about it

Comment: The HazelcastInstance is available as an osgi service.If your code is in osgi bundle you can access it by scr notation(eg: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics/blob/083573b50a2209f9906285b4903a08213ced02bc/components/analytics-processors/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.admin/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/analytics/spark/admin/internal/AnalyticsAdminComponent.java#L28) else if it in a palin jar you can access the osgi service through carbonContext api(https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon445/CarbonContext+API#CarbonContextAPI-ObjectgetOSGiService(Classclazz))